# How to monitoring folder files by vbs

Tags: vbscript

Can anyone help me where i do mistake ?
this script is for monitoring folder for create, delete or modified text files

```
sPath = "C:\scripts\test"
sComputer = "."
sDrive = split(sPath,":")(0)
sFolders1 = split(sPath,":")(1)
sFolders = REPLACE(sFolders1, "\", "\\") & "\\"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & sComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
("SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE " _
& "TargetInstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile' AND " _
& "TargetInstance.Drive='" & sDrive & "' AND " _
& "TargetInstance.Path='" & sFolders & "' AND " _
& "TargetInstance.Extension = 'txt' ")

Wscript.Echo vbCrlf & Now & vbTab & _
"Begin Monitoring for a Folder " & sDrive & ":" & sFolders1 & " Change Event..." & vbCrlf

Do
    Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    Select Case objLatestEvent.Path_.Class

    Case "__InstanceCreationEvent"
    WScript.Echo Now & vbTab & objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.FileName & "." & objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.Extension _
    & " was created" & vbCrlf

    Case "__InstanceDeletionEvent"
    WScript.Echo Now & vbTab & objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.FileName & "." & objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.Extension _
    & " was deleted" & vbCrlf

    Case "__InstanceModificationEvent"
    If objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.LastModified <> _
    objLatestEvent.PreviousInstance.LastModified then
    WScript.Echo Now & vbTab & objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.FileName & "." & objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.Extension _
    & " was modified" & vbCrlf
    End If
    End Select
Loop

Set objWMIService = nothing
Set colMonitoredEvents = nothing
Set objLatestEvent = nothing
```

This script is run perfect when i write

```
sPath = "\\ComputerName\C$\scripts\test"
```

insted of

```
sPath = "C:\scripts\test"
```

Thank you....

Comment: I don't see any problem.  What version of Windows?  Are you running this as administrator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you google for `"WMI TargetInstance.Drive"`, you'll see that the drive letter needs a colon. A query like

```
SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile' AND TargetInstance.Drive='E:' AND TargetInstance.Path='\\trials\\SoTrials\\answers\\10041057\\data\\' AND TargetInstance.Extension = 'txt'
```

works as expected.

Comment: Wow, great catch.  I didn't see that.